# NGINX block direct IP access with custom port

Tags: linux, nginx

I am trying to block diect ip access to my web apps. I want them to be accessible only via domain name. The reason is that I don't have SSL encryption if someone visits via ip address.

All web apps are running on different ports like IP_ADDRESS:4100, IP_ADDRESS:4200, ...

I tried things like this but it seems like it doesn't work for the ports

```
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name _;
 return 404;
}
```

I am looking for a solution that fixes all of my web apps at once, I dont want to add rules for each web app.
Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Just do not open those ports to the outer world and let nginx to do all the reverse proxy work with the SSL termination. Those web apps should be accessible for nginx only via the `127.0.0.1` loopback interface. If you can made your apps listening only `127.0.0.1:4100`, `127.0.0.1:4200`, etc, it would be even better.

Comment: Okey sounds good, but how do I achieve this?

Comment: How to setup you host system firewall is definitely an offtopic for [so] (if you don't know how to do it, I think [sf] will be the right place to ask). How to made your web app listening loopback interface only (obviously) depending on how your app is designed/developed, for the generic Node.JS HTTP server you should change [`server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlisten) method, from something like `app.listen(4200)` to `app.listen(4200, '127.0.0.1')` or `app.listen(4200, 'localhost')`.